# CreateJS - Can't get my spritesheet to animate

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, createjs

I've checked this forum/the internet/google forwards and backwards for my particular question, but to no avail.  I get examples that come close to mine - which I try to impart into my own example, but nothing doing.  Please help!  Again I apologize if this has been answered and I just overlooked, if so please throw me a link - otherwise here is my code:

All I'm trying to do is animate a single sprite image of a jumping Mega Man.
Thanks, and Happy Holidays!

NOTE: [Here the sprite I'm using](http://i943.photobucket.com/albums/ad274/Rah5er0/megaman__jump.png)

HERE IS MY: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrDoubleJump/f58mr0Lk/)

```
var stage, canvas,
bmpA, data,
megaman, spriteSheet;

function Main() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    container = new createjs.Container();

    megaman = new Image();
    megaman.src = "megaman__jump.png";
    var bmpA = new createjs.Bitmap(megaman);

    data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: [bmpA],
        frames: {
            width: 79,
            height: 139,
            count: 7
        },
        animations: {
            jump: [0, 6, "jump"]
        }
    });

    spriteSheet = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(data);
    spriteSheet.gotoAndPlay("jump");


    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", update);
}

function update(event) {
    stage.addChild(spriteSheet);
    stage.update();
}


</script>

</head>

<body onload = "Main();">
    <canvas id = "canvas" width = "780" height = "300"
        style = "border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Q1OQM.png
```

Comment: please make a fiddle to help better

Comment: Sure!  Here's my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MrDoubleJump/f58mr0Lk/

Comment: I recommend only adding the spritesheet to the stage once, when it is created. Adding it again will cause the children array to be modified, even though nothing is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick edit. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/f58mr0Lk/9/

1. Your Fiddle wasn't very helpful, since it was just your code pasted in. I modified it to drop the body tag (jsfiddle does that for you), import easeljs, and use the full image path.
2. The BitmapAnimation class was renamed to Sprite sometime ago. I am not sure what version of EaselJS you are using, but it might not have that class anymore.
3. I removed the Bitmap. The SpriteSheet data accepts either a string path, or an Image reference, not a Bitmap.
4. As I suggested below, I pulled out the entire update method, added the Sprite one time, and then had the tick just update the stage directly.

The fiddle "works" now, but the spritesheet dimensions don't seem right. Have a look.

```
data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    images: ["http://i943.photobucket.com/albums/ad274/Rah5er0/megaman__jump.png~original"],
    frames: {
        width: 79,
        height: 139,
        count: 7
    },
    animations: {
        jump: [0, 6, "jump"]
    }
});

var sprite = new createjs.Sprite(data);
```

Comment: Sorry about the Fiddle, I'm still a newbie. I've been watching some outdated tutorials - which would explain the 'Bitmap Animation' among other outdated discrepancies/redundancies. The image - I just pulled off the web for testing, I'm making a new one with uniform dimensions - anyway... Thank you, I really appreciate you taking a look - one learning curve resolved!

Comment: One more thing that I'm confused on: Since Fiddle takes care of the <body> tags - I'm a bit lost on how to handle the 'onload' in my original code.  When I put your edited code into my compiler I'm getting a blank canvas.  Thanks again.

Comment: The whole JavaScript block is wrapped in a function closure that is fired when the window loads. This is configurable in the Frameworks and Extensions panel on the left side.

Comment: -Got it.  Much appreciated!